# Java Spring Security Authentication Server does not display error description

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

My Java Spring Authentication and Authorization Server is working.

I want to solve the errors in the requests I send from a client according to the OAuth2 flow. But none of the errors I get are detailed. For example, this request sent to `/oauth2/authorize`:

```
https://MY_DOMAIN/authorize?
    response_type=code&
    client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&
    redirect_uri=MY_CALLBACK_URL&
    scope=SCOPE&
    state=STATE
```

Gives the following error after I enter credentials:

[image]

My goal is not to resolve the error here, but there are different errors I get like this and I need to see a more informative error message so I can debug them all.

The console also has a non-informative output that goes like this:

```
...
2022-08-15 15:52:33.739 DEBUG 50827 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-08-15 15:52:33.739 DEBUG 50827 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2022-08-15 15:52:33.739 DEBUG 50827 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error?protocol=oauth2&response_type=code&access_type&client_id=articles-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Flms%2Flogin&scope=openid%20articles.read&state=XqqDv6wx6O&code_challenge_method=plain&code_challenge=e964fe0c4b609ef3cf29658efc6077e7feb591f78c458c2092aa56c9
...
```

Comment: There should be more information on the error in your console or log files, it's generally bad practice to give detailed error information on a public facing page

Comment: There is. But they are not informative as well.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the logging level on things like springframework security as such `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace` in properties? Also the log you posted in the question relates to the return of the error page, not the calls that resulted in said error page

Comment: Yes, it's in debug. The keyword related to the error is only in these lines.